# Running PHP and R on AWS

Tags: php, r, amazon-web-services

I have PHP codes that I want to use for website development that would draw on R for graphing/analysis. Here is an example of an Rblogger doing so (I do not want to use Rshiny).

See [this link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-php-and-r/).

I would host the website on an EC2 instance.

Question is how can I host both the website and the Rstudio server at the same time? Amazon provides a link which goes to the Rstudio server. Would there be another link for hosting the website? Or do I *not* need to link/install the Rstudio server and simply run the R script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're already using PHP to host the site and act as the web server, then there's no direct need to have your R scripts interact directly with HTTP requests (and hence, would not require using RStudio server).

You can do what the author of the blog post did, which is spinning up the PHP server, and using the inline PHP commands to conditionally execute the R script (via bash), and then have PHP re-fetch the resulting artifact (graph image) to render it on the page.

If you were looking to scale this system out to handle a large number of requests, I'd suggest decoupling the R script from the PHP server, as you could run into severe bottlenecking, at which point you would likely have some sort of API gateway that wraps the underlying R code and adds authentication, load balancing, and more.

Comment: Where would R be installed then? on the PHP server or the AWS Linux EC2 server? Wouldn't I have to install the R package somewhere?

Comment: Yup! From inside of your Linux EC2 server, you can install the R runtime from your terminal with `sudo yum install -y R`

Comment: Once installed, you can run R scripts directly from bash with `R < scriptName.R --no-save`, which for your case, you'd need to invoke via bash from however PHP accepts that.

Comment: and I presume I would have to link PHP to S3 through some PHP library package to run the R script/collect output data/graphical image that would be saved on S3.

Comment: If you're planning on overwriting the same image repeatedly, storing it locally on EC2 should be just fine, and PHP can pull it from the instance's filesystem. However, if you want to persist that data, I'd recommend saving it to S3. If the image is created on the server through an R script, there's no need to send it over to S3 just to then have PHP call that (although this would be best practice for a more production-level application). Just think of S3 as long term storage backup in this case.